# Android RelativeLayout displaying jumbled up

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have simple RelativeLayout with multiple elements. But the display is not as expected with some elements jumbled and on top of each other. It seems very strange to me and I am unable to figure out why it is so. Please see the screenshot attached.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="#21759b"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Close" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add a missing Business"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#21759b"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerContactType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:entries="@array/contactType" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerContactType" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business Name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/speciality_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_layout" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/speciality"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business speciality" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/address_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/speciality_layout" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business Address" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address_layout" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business Phone" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone_layout" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business Email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/timings_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_layout" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="65"
        android:hint="Business Timings" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timings_layout"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="#21759b"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Submit.." />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: how do you want to look like your UI?

Comment: You need to rename android:id="@+id/name_phone" to 

android:id="@+id/phone_layout" as id phone_layout doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use LinearLayout in these situations and its easier to manage but
if you don't want to change, this is your fixed layout :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#21759b"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add a missing Business"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#21759b"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnClose"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerContactType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:entries="@array/contactType" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinnerContactType" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business Name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/speciality_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_layout" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/speciality"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business speciality" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/address_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/speciality_layout" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business Address" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/address_layout" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business Phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/phone_layout" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business Email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/timings_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_below="@id/email_layout" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/timings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="65"
            android:hint="Business Timings" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timings_layout"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#21759b"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Submit.." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> first problem with your code was in your case everywhere you used **android:layout_below** you should use *@id/view_id* because you had defined that view before and not *@+id/view_id*
>
> the second problem was you added **android:layout_below="@id/phone_layout"** and you didn't define *phone_layout* you had only a view id of *name_phone*

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. Updated as suggested and it works!

Comment: happy to help. if it works correctly please mark it as answer for anyone else with the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

in your relative layout use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and set proper value for `android:layout_marginTop`One more thing you are usin `android:layout_below="@+id/phone_layout"`but you haven't defined phone_layout

Answer (score 1):

I quick review shows that the `TextInputLayout` with id `email_layout` uses a `layout_below` with an unused id of `phone_layout`.

Perhaps you meant it to reference `name_phone`.  Doing so (or alternately changing the `name_phone` id) appears to remove the overlapping elements.

Also, I believe the use of `@+id/...` is only used for the first reference so subsequent references are typically `@id/...`

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier for yourself and use LinearLayout instead on a vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want your `email_layout` to be below `phone_layout`, but look - you don't have the layout with id `phone_layout` - instead of it you have `name_phone` id. So all you need is to change `name_phone` id to `phone_layout`. Good luck :)